# Count number of sets containing an element

Tags: notation, terminology

I am looking for some terminology that illustrates counting the number of indexed sets (eg Si) containing a particular element (eg p).

Comment: If $I$ is the index set of $(S_i)_{i \in I}$, then $|\{i \in I: p \in S_i\}|$ is the number of indexed sets $S_i$ containing $p$. Does this help you?

Comment: I will check later and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks again and if you add as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My pleasure.

If $I$ is the index set of $(S_i)_{i \in I}$, then $|\{i \in I: p \in S_i\}|$ is the number (i.e., cardinal) of indexed sets $S_i$ containing $p$.